# Why is there a colour difference in the end result in a PDF: cmyk-to-cmyk and rgb-to-cmyk workflow comparison

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, color-profile, prepress

My Illustrator working profile is set to sRGB/Coated FOGRA39 and to preserve embedded profiles. Conversion Adobe ACE / Perceptual.

I did a test. I made a print ready PDF in two different ways:

In the first I linked an sRGB psd-file to the layout and to the second I linked a PSD already converted to fogra cmyk in Photoshop. There I used the Perceptual conversion as well.

I exported the PDF similarly in both cases: Convert to destination (Preserve numbers), to working cmyk (this case the same FOGRA39). I tested the CMYK psd also without conversion in the export part, and the result appeared the same.

When I look at these files in Acrobat through the Fogra39 profile, they appear different. The one that had RGB pictures converted in the export is a bit brighter, and the one with ready CMYK pictures a bit more dull/gray. I have understood that the conversion process on both programs (PS or AI) should be the same, but still I get different results.

Is someone able to spot where the difference could come from?

Comment: Hard to tell without having access to the files and seeing each step. What about *Black Point Compensation*? Same settings there? And do you preview in Acrobat with the exact same settings in *Output Preview*, using the correct profile?

Comment: Yes I was viewing through coated fogra39 in both cases in acrobat. The black point compensation setting I assume had it chosen in both, but not totally sure. Need to recheck this later.

Comment: I'll see later if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also try opening the images from the PDFs in Photoshop using the *Edit Object* tool in Acrobat. Can be easier to compare in Photoshop.

Comment: I tested the 4 rendering intents in both Illustrator and InDesign. It seems that Illustrator **only** gives the expected result with *Relative Colorimetric*! For *Perceptual*, *Saturation* and *Absolute Colorimetric* the image converted by Illustrator looks different (worse) than the image converted by Photoshop. In InDesign all 4 rendering intents seem to work as expected with no (visible) difference. It's terrible really! Just another reason for me to not use Illustrator as anything else than a vector drawing application. (It's a bit confusing to test - somebody else please check this too.)

Comment: Annoying, since illustrator is much used on complex shape layouts (like packaging). It's hard to understand all of these things and these kind of problems make me even more confused.

I had a look and yes, I had black point compensation chosen on both. 

I tested again like this: I put both pictures (RGB and CMYK) on same file on different pages, did the export on convert to destination. With indd there is no  difference between the pages in acrobat, but with illustrator there is. The one that I converted in photoshop seems to look like the same that Indesign converted are.

Comment: OK, so we get the same results. But I can't answer your question as to *why* this is happening. Sure seems like a bug. Funny thing about graphic design software. First you spend years trying to learn how to do stuff correctly. Then you start to find all the small inaccuracies and bugs which you also have to learn how to navigate through. I can manage, but when I explain stuff to beginners the explanation gets longer and longer. 

Comment: Thank you, and you put my pain into words excactly. I'm still learning and now even more I don't know what would be the correct way to do these things. I guess my real question here was, am I making the mistake or the program :D